# como recuperar una imagen obtenida de una API

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola amigos buenas espero esten muy bien tengo un problema al tratar de obtener una imagen que obtengo con una API e investigado y e encontrado algo sobre blob.
este seria un fragmento de la respuesta de la API ya que es demasiado largo

> �PNG001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\u0006@\0\0\u0004�\b\u0006\0\0\0�\u0001��\0\0
>   \0IDATx���ێ$I�%vD/f�\u001e�̌�UW�̂\v�\u0004���q\0�\u000fC���_�\u0003�\n\u0002K�3g��!�/\u001c�NWwWuUgf�%���\u0017>������t/酨Ȉp7SS\u0015��9\"�����SN1\"ƈ�3\b@�\t1\u0006d�+�\f�\u0018\u0003c\f|��w\u001d�w\0�eY0�#N�\u0013�yB\f\u0001�\u0010��C�\u000f��\u00068ca�\u0001�5�a�0����\u0016�`�f��\f��\t\u0004䌔3b\b��\u0005I��\u000f\u0003.�{\\^]���\nKJ�C�\u001f��\u0011�\u07bf/��\u000e�9\u0018c\0�<+\0\u0010Q�}�y�3\0Xkᜃ�\u001e�{�\u0010\u0010B�<�X�\u0005D�Da<�\u0018\u0003�\\y��vu��3�7�̃�C��sD�)!��eY0M\u0013�eA\b\u0001\u0004�\u0010�q9��\a\u0011!猔\u0012RJ����3nǣ\u007f���{W���M)!�\\ơ���fy\bcL���G;�z��=:\u0017�8ۗ~�9WƝR*s�gn�[�ܮe��:v\0H)���=umu̺���\u0018\"����\u0005˦\u07bb\u001d;\u0011��)cP��1\"�\0\u0010!\u0013VcZͿ\\�62��oȬ潝7��v.ڵ���x�{�N�Yc`Ȕk�l������~�<

y este seria el metodo que me devuelve la respuesta para obtener la imagen

```
 using (var responseImg = await httpClient.GetAsync("designs/" + id_design + "/render"))
            {
                responseDataImg = await responseImg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

espero me puedan ayudar y esto lo estoy haciendo con asp.net C#, saludos

Comment: No puede usar Content.ReadAsStreamAsync() o Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync() ?

Comment: no, me lanza un error en la linea de codigo

Comment: si invocas la api desde PostMan que respuesta recibes ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberias analizar

[Efficiently Streaming Large HTTP Responses With HttpClient](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient)

alli notaras que usa

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    const string url = $"designs/{id_design}/render";
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        string fileToWriteTo = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
        }
    }
}
```

en este caso baja el archivo fisicamente a un temporal por eso usa `Path.GetTempFileName()`, pero sino quieres esto y la idea es obtener el byte array veras que `streamToReadFrom` es un `MemoryStream`

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    const string url = $"designs/{id_design}/render";
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var result = streamToReadFrom.ToArray();
    }
}
```